# How to override HTML image using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have my current code:

```
#content img[src="/img/test.gif"] { 
    background-image:url(dark-img.png) !important;
}
```

From my understanding `!important;` overrides existing values?

Why isn't this overriding the current HTML image in place there? The background shows up, **behind** the HTML image.

I want it **in front** of the HTML image, is this possible using CSS or JS?

Edit: For what its worth, im making a userscript that will modify the existing style of the site. So I do not have direct access to the HTML image.

Comment: The image of an `img` element is not a "existing background-image value". Background images and "normal" (foreground, content) images are two separate things and you can't use one to override the other.

Comment: Wrong tool. You want to use JS for this.

Comment: Not necessary the wrong tool. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your 'userscript' to change 'src' attribute value.

If there is an ID there, you can do this:

```
document.getElementById('TheImgId').src = 'yournewimagesrc';
```

If there is no ID:

```
var imgElements = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
```

Do iteration of `imgElements`. When its `src` value is match with your criteria, change the value with your own, do break.

**Update:**

Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function ChangeImageSrc(oldSrc, newSrc) {
        var imgElements = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
        for (i = 0; i < imgElements.length; i++){
            if (imgElements[i].src == oldSrc){
                imgElements[i].src = newSrc;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/eu757.png" />
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPB9t.png" />
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPB9t.png" />
<script language="javascript">
    setTimeout("ChangeImageSrc('https://i.stack.imgur.com/eu757.png', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPB9t.png')", 5000);
</script>
```

**Preview**:

[image]

The first image will be replaced after 5 secs. Try **[Live Demo](http://jeaffreygilbert.com/ChangeSrcByJs.html)**.

Comment: You've lost me completely, I've hardly ever touched JS let alone GM.

Comment: `src` of `img` is not style, cannot be overrided with CSS. Everybody suggests you to use Javascript.

Comment: I understand that bit. The image contains no ID, its just pure HTML, with src="image2.jpg". I tried the 'If there is no ID' thing and it doesnt seem to work from what im trying. Do I need to learn JS before I go any further into this mod? (requires 2 images to be done via JS, by the looks of things).

Comment: You don't need javascript. See my answer

Answer (score 13):

You don't need javascript for image replacement! As long as you can identify the image by a CSS selector, you can use CSS to do the trick.

See the solution here
http://www.audenaerde.org/csstricks.html#imagereplacecss

Comment: Genius... some people are tweaking things in places where they dont have access to js nor html (for example VOC templates in Dynamics) this is an amazing way of doing this with pure css...

Comment: @EgliBecerra This also can help to change particular tab favicons in Firefox using userChrome.css! This solution is really unthinkable!

Answer (score 11):

Here is the code [using only css](http://www.audenaerde.org/csstricks.html#imagereplacecss):

```
<img src="tiger.jpg" 
     style="padding: 150px 200px 0px 0px; 
            background: url('butterfly.jpg'); 
            background-size:auto; 
            width:0px; 
            height: 0px;">
```

- sets the image size to 0x0,
- adds a border of the desired size (150x200), and
- uses your image as a background-image to fill.

If you upvote this answer, give [@RobAu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10396698/1587329) an upvote, too.

Comment: This approach does require a known/fixed size image though right?

Comment: @rainabba: You fix the size of the space. If the background image is larger, it is cropped. If it is smaller, it is tiled.

Answer (score 2):

The `background-image` property, when applied to an image, refers to (drum roll ... ) the background-image of the image. It will always be behind the image.

If you want the image to appear in *front* of the image, you are going to have to use two images, or another container with a background-image that covers the first image.

BTW, it is bad practice to rely on `!important` for overriding. It can also be ineffective since 1) it can't override declarations in an element's style attribute, and 2) it only works if it *can* work based on the markup and the current CSS. In your case, all the huffing and puffing and `!important` declarations won't make an image do something it can't do.

Comment: Yeah sorry - not thinking clearly. I understand its the background image. Is there a way I can override it using Javascript? (thinking GM).

Comment: You can definitely override it using Javascript. Just get a reference to the image (let's say "myImage") and do `myImage.src = "dark-img.png"` or whatever urlyou want.

Answer (score 2):

The replacement of an image in CSS can be done in several ways. 
Each of them has some drawbacks (like semantics, seo, browsercompatibility,...)

On this link 9 (**nine!**) different techniques are discussed in a very good way :

http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/

If you are interested in css in general : the whole site is worth a look.

Answer (score 2):

I answered a similar question in another SO page..

https://robau.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/override-image-src-in-css/

```
<img src="linkToImage.jpg" class="egg">

.egg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0 0 200px 0;
  background-image: url(linkToImage.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

So effectively hiding the image and padding down the background. Oh what a hack but if you want an with alt text and a background that can scale without using Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to place the first image as a background-image too. Then you can override it. You could do in a "standard" css file for the site, and every user gets its own, where he can override what he wants.

Comment: I cant change the first image, as its run by the site owner - not me. Its to modify the site using Stylish.

Answer (score 0):

i agree with all the answers here, just thought id point out that 'browsers' such as IE won't like the img[src="/img/test.gif"] as a means of selecting the image. it would need a class or id.

Comment: Older versions of IE won't like it. It should be fine in IE8, though.

Answer (score 0):

The images shown in  tags are in the foreground of the element, not the background, so setting a background image in an  won't override the image; it'll just appear behind the main image, as you're seeing.

What you want to do is replace the image. Here's your options:

- Start with an element with a background image, not an  tag. Then changing the background image in CSS will replace it.
- Start with an  tag, but use Javascript to change the src attribute. (this can't be done in CSS, but is simple enough in JS)

EDIT:

Seeing your edit in the question, I'd suggest option 2 - use Javascript to change the src attribute. It's quite simple; something like this would do the trick:

```
document.getElementById('myimgelement').src='/newgraphic.jpg';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to replace it by just doing something like:

```
.image {
    content: url('https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/400');
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Unfortunately seems that it does not work in Firefox :(